# data showing but not showing in useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  const response = product.map((item) => {
    return item.images;
  });
  console.log("response is ", response);
  const [productItem, setProductItem] = useState(response);

  console.log("usestate is ", productItem);
```

[image: output of this code]

please help me as soon as possible I am stuck here for like 3 days and don't know what to do

I have tried alot to solve this issue and it is working in console before usestate initialization but once I add usestate hook it will not show up

Comment: your code seems ok but you may have made a mistake somewhere else in your code. take a look at this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-http-yz1hld

Comment: Can you create a runnable code where you can reproduce your problem, You can use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) if you want...

Answer (score 0):

Initially declare the state as null / empty array

```
const [productItem, setProductItem] = useState(null)
```

Then use `useEffect` to set the response to state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const product = [........]

  const response = product.map((item) => {
    return item.images;
  });
  
  setProductItem(response)
},[])
```

Comment: Thank you, buddy. It was so simple But I don't know I couldn't get that idea thanks again

Comment: it worked for a while Now i don't know it's not working again

Comment: Share your trying snippet.

Comment: const [productItem, setProductItem] = useState(null);    

  const { id } = useParams();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { loading, product, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetail
  );

  const response = product.map((item) => {
    return item.images[0].url;
  });
  console.log("response is ", response);
  useEffect(() => {
    setProductItem(response);
  }, []);
  console.log(productItem);